# How to use controller service api from a dependency

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a custom controller service that I want to use together with the `ConnectWebSocket` processor. The controller service depends on `nifi-websocket-services-api` and does not need a custom api (the my-customer-controller-service-api folder is empty). I have written a test for the controller service and it is passing.

However I cannot select the controller service, because `ConnectWebSocket` only accepts a controller service api from `nifi-websocket-service-api-nar`.

[image]

I want to avoid to recode the entire `ConnectWebSocket` processor. So my question is:

Is it possible to configure the dependencies such that my custom controller service uses the api that comes from `nifi-websocket-service-api-nar`?

pom.xml of controller-service:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-controllerservice-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>nifi-controllerservice</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <!-- normal dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-websocket-services-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-websocket-services-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-ssl-context-service-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

pom.xml of controller-service-nar

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-controllerservice-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-controllerservice-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <source.skip>true</source.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-controllerservice</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-websocket-services-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>nar</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

root pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-controllerservice-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>nifi-comtom</module>
        <module>nifi-comtom-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the standard way processors and controller services work...

Processors depend on an interface which comes from the service API NAR, and controller service implementations implement that interface. The framework then knows all the implementations of that interface which allows is to provide the possible services that can be used.

Without seeing your project and poms it is hard to say what the problem is, but most likely it is a dependency issue. Your project structure should have two Maven modules,  one that produces a jar for your service impl, lets call this one custom-service, and then one that packages the NAR, lets call this custom-service-nar.

The custom-service module should have a provided dependency on nifi-websocket-services-api, this allows it to compile, but we don't want to bundle that API since at runtime it will come from another NAR.

The custom-service-nar module should have a dependency of type NAR on the nifi-websocket-services-api-nar.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-LinkingProcessorsandControllerServices

Comment: I added the pom files to my question. I have setup dependencies as you describe. The custom controller service shows up in the controller services tab, but it does not show up in the controller service settings of the the ConnectWebSocket processor.

Comment: The poms are not setup as I described... in controller-service pom, nifi-websocket-services-api must be scope of provided, not compile... in controller-service-nar pom you need a dependency of <type>nar</type> on nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar, remove all the ones that have <scope>nar</scope>

Comment: After removing the other dependencies that have <scope>nar</scope> I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/ssl/RestrictedSSLContextService from nifi log

Comment: The poms look correct, RestrictedSSLContext service comes from nifi-standard-services-api-nar which should be in the chain you have setup... controller-service-nar -> nifi-websocket-jetty-nar -> nifi-websocket-api-nar -> nifi-standard-services-api-nar

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception to question?

Comment: Please share your controller class declaration.

Comment: Not totally sure what the issue is with your setup, but here is an example that works for me, I am able to select CustomWebSocketService from the ConnectWebSocket processor - https://github.com/bbende/nifi-custom-websocket-bundle